# Physical Backup of Maria DB as a snapshot using LVM

Tags: backup, lvm, snapshot, sql, mariadb

I have a SQL database which I want to backup as a snapshot. I want to use LVM to do so, but I am not able to do it. Also my database is not stored in a LVM partition but its located in my `/dev/sda2` partition.

So how do I get it done? I have just tried creating a snapshot of a LVM partition which I had created for testing purpose and it was a success, but not able to create the same with `/dev/sda2`.

Answer (score 2):

If your device /dev/sda2 is not "under" LVM, you can't manage it through LVM.